# Gutters in front of corner pilasters, how to put gutters on a Georgian house?

Tags: gutters, architecture

I am looking at buying a Georgian style colonial and the house has very handsome corner pilasters, however, over each one is a gutter downspout, so it kind of spoils the effect of the pilasters. I mean it is almost silly to put fancy articulated corners on a building and then position downspouts right over them. Below is detail showing the problem:

[image]

So, you can see from the photo that the downspout is right over the pilaster and ruins its appearance. In the rear of the building there are downspouts both over the pilasters AND flanking the doorway which looks even worse.

How can improve the appearance of the building by changing the water management system to be invisible or less conspicuous?

Comment: There are ways to route rainwater internally but they cause huge problems in the long run.  Hopefully we can find something else. Can you post better pictures including one of the whole house, one of another corner that  has nothing blocking the "pilaster" and shows the materials in use, and a closeup of this corner showing the downspout and electrical service conduit more clearly?  I see what looks like a corner bead between the downspout and the conduit.  Not sure if that is the detail you are referring to, or there is something else behind the downspout that we can't see.

Comment: Have you considered painting them to match the siding and pilasters? Going one step further and adding darker lines to simulate the siding?

Comment: Maybe post full size images to imgur.com and post links to them here so people can see what's going on there.